# Store Rails Engine user image uploads in the engine or in the main app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I have implemented a yelp-like Rails 4 engine--things / reviews of things / ratings / photos of things / registered users / likes.

The engine components are all namespaced to keep them isolated from the main app.

But what about the user uploaded images?

1. Store them in the **engine root:** public/engine_namespace/photographs/...
2. Store them in the **main app root:** public/engine_namespace/photographs/...

I lean towards keeping uploads isolated in the engine's directory structure. But is there a best practices guideline or a functional argument for whether to store Rails engine uploads in the engine or in the main app?

Comment: Engine provides functionality to main application. Main application is responsible for data. So image should be stored in main application.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, the underlying argument for one or the other. Thank you.

Comment: @FlorentFerry If you'd like to make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.